# Terraform azure output of multiple network interfaces assigning to a single vm

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hashicorp

not sure if anyone has come across this issue before, i have multiple network interfaces that i need to attach to a vm in Azure, i am passing in network interface details as a map. i need to use the output of network interfaces and apply it to the network_interface_ids in vm resource. my current code to assign network_interface_ids doesn't seem to be getting the network interface ids from output of azurerm_network_interface. Here is the short snapshot of the code i have:

```
 resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vmNic" {
  for_each = var.network_interfaces

  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value.name}-ip"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = each.value.private_ip
  }  
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {   
  count = length(azurerm_network_interface.vmNic)
  name                = var.vm_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = try(azurerm_network_interface.vmNic.*.id[count.index], null)
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong here in assigning the network_interface_ids?

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages? What is expected outcome, and what your code does now?

Comment: changed the wording slightly, hopefully that makes sense now

Comment: What is the exact form of `var.network_interfaces`. Also please don't use "doesn't seem to be getting". Exactly what's happening? Any error messages? Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to create multiple NICs and attach them to a single VM, and the variable `network_interfaces` looks like a list with object elements. So if I'm right. You can change the code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vmNic" {
  count               = length(var.network_interfaces)

  name                = element(var.network_interfaces, count.index)["name"]
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${element(var.network_interfaces, count.index)["name"]}-ip"
    subnet_id                     = element(var.network_interfaces, count.index)["subnet_id"]
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = element(var.network_interfaces, count.index)["private_ip"]
  }  
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {   
  count = length(azurerm_network_interface.vmNic)
  name                = var.vm_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = azurerm_network_interface.vmNic.*.id
```

The variable `network_interfaces` here looks like this:

```
variable "network_interfaces" {
    default = [
        {
            name = "test1",
            subnet_id = "xxxxxx",
            private_ip = "x.x.x.x"
        },
        {
            name = "test2",
            subnet_id = "xxxxxx",
            private_ip = "x.x.x.x"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you @Charles Xu , i made my map of network_interfaces look like yours and it works